# cannot find module - relative path

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I'm running a test by the follwoing code and getting an error says:

```
Failed: cannot find module '../page/home_page.js
```

The main page is:

```js
describe("login to website",function(){
     var employeeId;
     var employeeBday;
     
    beforeEach(function(){
        browser.get("https://pre-www5.main.co.il/#/");
    });
   
    it("should succees login",function(){
        employeeId = "54729108";
        employeeBday = "25/03/1957";
        var home_page = require('../page/home_page.js')
        
        home_page.enterUsernameField(employeeId);
        home_page.enterBirthdateField(employeeBday);
        var pick_present_page = home_page.clickContinue();
        
        element(by.xpath("//*[@id='planAndDev']/div/div/div/div/matanot/form/div[2]/h4")).getText().then(function(text)
        {
            expect(text).toContain("foo")
        });
                      
    });

});
```

And using the home_page class:

```js
require ('../page/pick_present_page.js')
var home_page = function(){

    this.enterUsernameField=function(employeeId){
        element(by.xpath("//*[@id='planAndDev']/div/div/div/div/form/fieldset/div[1]/input")).sendKeys(employeeId);
    };
    this.enterBirthdateField=function(EmployeebDay){
         element(by.xpath("//*[@id='planAndDev']/div/div/div/div/form/fieldset/div[2]/my-date-picker/div/div/input")).sendKeys(EmployeebDay);
    };
    this.clickContinue=function(){
        element(by.xpath("//*[@id='planAndDev']/div/div/div/div/form/nav/div/button")).click();
        return require('./pick_present_page');
    };
module.exports = new home_page();
};
```

The project folder located in `C:\JS_Project`
and the pages are located in `C:\JS_Project\page` 
It looks like I'm doing something wrong the way i'm using the relative path.

Comment: What folder is your test in?

Comment: which is your root folder
../ means returning from a folder.
`'../page/pick_present_page.js'` means you are returning from some folder and accessing *pick_present_page.js* in *page* folder

Comment: my 'conf.js'  folder located in 'C:\JS_Project'. And then I'm running it by: 'protractor conf.js'. The 'beforeEach' is being executed and then it fails.

Comment: if your test is in the root folder, `var home_page = require('../page/home_page.js')` probably should be `var home_page = require('./page/home_page.js')`

Comment: what is the difference, if may I ask. Between one dot ot two dots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should stablish the relative path to the SpecFile, not from the config file.

So if your project have:

Project

- page

  - home_page.js
  - pick_present_page.js
- conf.js
- specs

  - main

you should get the page from "../page/home_page.js"

Main

```
'use strict;'
let HomePage = require('../page/home_page.js');

describe("login to website",function(){
    let employeeId;
    let employeeBday;
    let home = new HomePage();

    beforeEach(function(){
        browser.get("https://pre-www5.main.co.il/#/");
    });

    it("should login successfully",function(){
        employeeId = "54729108";
        employeeBday = "25/03/1957";

        home.enterUsernameField(employeeId);
        home.enterBirthdateField(employeeBday);
        var pick_present_page = home.clickContinue();

        element(by.xpath("//*[@id='planAndDev']/div/div/div/div/matanot/form/div[2]/h4")).getText().then(function(text)
        {
            expect(text).toContain("foo")
        });

    });
});
```

Home_Page

```
   'use strict;'
   require ('../page/pick_present_page.js');

   var HomePage = function(){
       let employeeField = element(by.xpath("//*[@id='planAndDev']/div/div/div/div/form/fieldset/div[1]/input"));
       let employeeBDayField = element(by.xpath("//*[@id='planAndDev']/div/div/div/div/form/fieldset/div[2]/my-date-picker/div/div/input"));
       let continueButton = element(by.xpath("//*[@id='planAndDev']/div/div/div/div/form/nav/div/button"));

        this.enterUsernameField=function(employeeId){
            employeeField.sendKeys(employeeId);
        };

        this.enterBirthdateField=function(EmployeebDay){
             employeeBDayField.sendKeys(EmployeebDay);
        };

        this.clickContinue=function(){
            continueButton.click();
            return require('./pick_present_page');
        };
    };
    module.exports = HomePage;
```

Comment: Regarding your comment, ".." is accessing an upper folder and "." is accessing to the current one.

Comment: I did exactly as your suggestion. including configuring the spec folder as : specs: ['specs/women_day_spec.js'] in the conf.js file. 
I'm now getting a failure says: Failed: home_page.EnterUserNameField is not a function

Comment: is not a function at C:\JS_Project\specs\women_day_spec.js

Comment: @YanivEliav variable and function name is case-sensitive. It should be `home_page.enterUserNameField(employeeId)`

Comment: @Alf thanks. I didn't change it. I left it as home_page. and I used the method exactly as it is in home_page class so it's not the case sensitive issue. as you can see, the error says something about "is not a function at C:\JS_Project\specs\women_day_spec.js". why would it look for a method in spec file while the original method is in home_page and I'm just calling it..?

Comment: @YanivEliav Hi again, what i'm wondering is if your function name matches in the Spec and the Page. Because you posted `enterUserNameField ` and the function in the page file is named `enterUsernameField `
 * EDIT *
You should update the posted code to match exactly yours

Comment: @Alf as far as I can see they are the same :-)
When using the part you suggested : let home = new HomePage();
I'm getting an error that the HomePage is not a constructor.

Comment: @YanivEliav Did you used my entire code? or are you patching yours? That error says that Page element is not correclty exposed as a function OR the module.export is not correctly happening.

Comment: patched it and used the important things you mentioned.

Comment: Then update the post with your patched code, because i've been looking into my code and there's no issues around there.

Comment: I will. but I would like to know what was the issue for the future.thanks!

Comment: @YanivEliav The issue is linked the way you are exposing the Page, you are doing it inside the function home_page and you should do it outside (as you can see on my example). Good luck out there, wild testing awaits! * EDIT * if you create a new instance inside the own function it will cause problems, try to expose as Object and then init it on the spec, it's a better way to do it.  (Look for Page Object Design Pattern)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info